# Why must the determinant of the hessian of a scalar function be positive for there to be a local min/max? Intuition needed

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Is there any intuition behind having the determinant of the Hessian matrix being negative corresponding to a saddle point, and positive corresponding to a max/min depending on the sign of $f_{xx}$ for a function of two variables?

I made up a story for myself to remember. Since, assuming symmetry of mixed partials
$$
\Delta=f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2
$$
Looks a bit like a sort of commutator. I tell myself that if it is negative, somehow the functions behavior is too wacky, since the change in the function with respect to $x$ and then $y$ dominates the concavity in the two coordinate directions. Is there anything to that/does it make sense? I am also not sure how to think about mixed partials geometrically, is there a good way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an intuitive explanation.  The second order approximation to $f$ near $x_0 \in \mathbb R^2$ is $f(x) \approx f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0)^T (x - x_0) + \frac12 (x - x_0)^T \nabla^2 f(x_0) (x - x_0)$.  If $x_0$ is a local extremum for $f$, then $\nabla f(x_0) = 0$, so the behavior of $f$ near $x_0$ is determined by the quadratic term.  If $\nabla^2 f(x_0)$ is positive definite, then $(x - x_0)^T \nabla^2 f(x_0) (x - x_0) \geq 0$ for all $x$, so $x_0$ is a local minimum.

Comment: This is an awesome answer, the taylor's series helped a lot

Answer (score 6):

Let $f:D \subseteq \Bbb R^2 \to R$ be a twice differentiable function.  Then we'd call $f$ a *surface*.

The directional derivative $D_vf(x,y)$ is the derivative of $f$ at $(x,y)$ in the direction of the unit vector $v$.  This gives the scalar slope at $(x,y)$ in that direction.

[image]

The *second* directional derivative ${D_v}^2f(x,y)$ is the second derivative of $f$ at $(x,y)$ in the direction of the unit vector $v$.  This gives the concavity at $(x,y)$ in that direction.

[image]

The Hessian $Hf(x,y)$ at a point $(x,y)$ is really a *bilinear form*.  That is, it's a function that takes two direction vectors and produces a number.  If both of those direction vectors are the same, then it just gives the value of the second directional derivative (i.e. the concavity).

$$[Hf(x,y)](v,v) = {D_v}^2f(x,y)$$

The matrix that you're used to calling the Hessian is really just the matrix representation of this bilinear form with respect to an orthonormal basis.

$$\begin{bmatrix} f_{xx} & f_{xy} \\ f_{yx} & f_{yy}\end{bmatrix}$$

A bilinear form $B$ is **positive-definite** (resp. **negative-definite**) if $B(w,w)\gt 0$ (resp. $\lt 0$) for all $w\ne 0$.  So then we can see that the concavity of $f$ at $(x,y)$ is *positive* (resp. negative) in **all directions** iff the Hessian $Hf(x,y)$ is positive-definite (resp negative-definite).  This of course means that the surface has a *minimum* (resp. maximum) at that point.

OK.  So where does the determinant come in?  Well, checking *every* vector $w$ is kinda hard, so instead we can use properties of positive- and negative-definite bilinear forms.  For instance, we can determine if a bilinear form is positive- and negative-definite by checking the eigenvalues of its matrix representation in *any* basis.  If all of the eigenvalues are positive (resp. negative), then the bilinear form is positive-definite (resp. negative-definite).

Alternatively, we can use [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), which says that equivalently, a Hermitian matrix is positive-definite if all of its principal minors are positive.

The principal minors of a matrix are the determinants of the following submatrices:

[image]

I.e. $f_{xx}>0$ and $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}f_{yx}>0$ in the $2\times 2$ case.

Somewhat similarly, the condition for negative-definiteness is that the principal minors alternate with the first being negative.  I.e. $f_{xx}<0$ and $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}f_{yx}>0$ in the $2\times 2$ case.

A saddle point happens (sufficient but not necessary condition) when one of the eigenvalues of the matrix representing the Hessian is negative and the other positive.  Geometrically this means that the concavity in one direction is negative and in some other direction is positive (those two directions being the directions of the *eigenvectors*).  In that case the determinant will be *negative*.  So the condition is $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}f_{yx}<0$ in the $2\times 2$ case.

So that's where the multivariable second derivative test comes from: basic linear algebra.

Comment: What an amazing answer. What linear algebra textbook do you recommend that covers all the way up to positive definite matrices and bilinear forms as a topic? None of the ones I have do that. Maybe they are too applied or not geared towards optimization? Also, what programs do you use to make the beautiful figures and animations?

Comment: I'm also curious how you made these pictures!

Comment: @qbert Try *Linear Algebra and Geometry* by Shafarevich and Remizov.  I didn't make any of those images -- I just Googled them.  If you're interested, though, Mathematica can make pretty good images -- in addition to all the math you can do with it.  It's definitely well-worth getting the student edition assuming of course that you are a student.  Alternatively, I use PGF/TikZ when I'm making a image for a PDF or $\LaTeX$ file.The animated gif I'm afraid I don't know how to replicate.

Comment: Apparently the gif was also made with Mathematica.  You can ask [the actual artist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Blacklemon67) about it if you like.

Comment: @Bye_World thank you for all the info, checking out linear algebra and geometry from the library now :)

Answer (score 0):

This is to ensure all eigenvalues have the same signs. Along each eigenvector direction, the curves are all concave or all convex. If you have one concave in one direction and convex in another direction, it will be saddle.

Comment: ok, it is clear to me I need to read up on more than just basic linear algebra. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think of the curvature of (the surface given by) the function $f$ at $f(x)$ along the linearly independent directions through $x$.  For every such direction $d$ (a unit vector), define the function
$$
\phi_d(t) = f(x + td), \quad t \in ]-A, A[, \; A > 0.
$$
This, $\phi_d(0) = f(x)$, and if $x$ is a minimum, then $\phi_d''(0) > 0$.

Now,
$$
\phi_d''(t) = {d^2 \over dt^2} f(x + t d),
$$
which leads us to the Hessian.  Instead of requiring that $\phi_d'' > 0$ for {\em every} direction $d$ through $x$, we just need that to be true for every eigendirection of the Hessian.